# Performing Node analysis with more

Tags: thevenin, nodal-analysis, norton

Following a previous question problem regarding the node analysis with dependent source in a circuit I made some extensions that I would appreciate some validation if someone know.

I have the following circuit as shown in picture. I think that node equation would be: \$ -10 + \frac{V_{0}}{4} + \frac{V_{0} - 2 i_{1}}{6} = 0 \$ , with \$i_{1} = \frac{V_{0}}{6}\$. Am I correct?

[image]

Additionally I added another resistor a 3 Ω in parallel.I think that now I have 2 node equations:

\$-10 + \frac{V_{1}}{4}\ +\frac{V_{1}-V_{2}}{2i_{1}}=0\$

\$\frac{V_{2}-V_{1}}{2i_{1}} + \frac{V_{2}}{6} + \frac{V_{2}}{3}=0\$

with \$i_{1}\$ this time to be with current division (since 3 and 6 Ω resistors are in parallel):  \$i_{1} = \frac{3}{9}*10 = 30/9\$
Can someone correct me if I am wrong? I would appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: The first one is wrong.  And the second one with the two nodes is also not ok.  What if instead of CCVS you will have a 2V voltage source?

Comment: Why do you think that I1 = Vo/6Ω?

Comment: @G36 is similar with the previous one in the other previous post.Probably I need another node ? Please help.

Comment: For the first circuit. What is the voltage drop across 6Ω in terms of a nodal voltage? The "bottom" leg is at GND (0V) but the "top leg" is at?

Comment: @g36 I am sorry I do not understand it.What is bottom leg and the top leg? . If I have understood correctly the ground is the node below the 4 ohm resistor.

Comment: Also here $$\frac{V_{2}-V_{1}}{2\Omega i_{1}}$$ The denominator has a unit of Voltage. So you divide Voltage by Voltage. So, this is wrong.

Comment: OK https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOy3b.png Vx voltage is?

Comment: @G36 \$\frac{V_{x}}{6}\$ ?

Comment: Yes, and the Vx is equal to??

Comment: @g36 I don't know what V_x is equal to.probably V_x = i_1 * 6 ?

Comment: How about this one $$V_X =  V_O + 2I_1$$ Do you see it? Because the unit of \$2\Omega \times I_1\$ is a Voltage. And this is the CCVS voltage.

Comment: @g36 what are the node equations for this circuit ?

Comment: Won't you try to write them again yourself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148626/discussion-between-homer-jay-simpson-and-g36).

Answer (score 0):

I'm really impressed, looking at the chat log. I thought I'd add a few ways I might have written this out for the first case you worked out on your own:

[image]

Let's first keep the KVL *constraint* you mention:

[image]

Then:

$$\begin{align*}
&\rlap{\text{The currents sinking in the resistors must equal the source:}}\\\\
&\frac{V_o}{4\:\Omega}+\frac{V_x=V_o+2\cdot i_1}{6\:\Omega}=10\:\text{A}\\\\
&\rlap{\text{But }}\quad\quad i_1=\frac{V_x}{6\:\Omega}=\frac{V_o+2\cdot i_1}{6\:\Omega},\text{ or, solving for }i_1, \text{ find } i_1=\frac14 V_o:\\\\
&\frac{V_o}{4\:\Omega}+\frac{V_o+2\cdot \frac14 V_o}{6\:\Omega}=10\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

That's it. This solves out as \$V_o=20\:\text{V}\$. And from there you can work out \$i_1\$ and also \$V_x\$.

Or just start this way, instead:

$$\begin{align*}
&&i_1&=\frac{V_x}{6\:\Omega}=\frac{V_o+2\cdot i_1}{6\:\Omega}\\\\
&&\therefore i_1&=\frac14 V_o\\\\
&&\therefore V_o&=4\cdot i_1\\\\
\rlap{\text{KCL:}}\\\\
&&\frac{V_o}{4\:\Omega}+i_1&=10\:\text{A}\\\\
&&\frac{4\cdot i_1}{4\:\Omega}+i_1&=10\:\text{A}\\\\
&&i_1+i_1&=10\:\text{A}\\\\
&&i_1&=5\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

From that you know right away that \$V_x=30\:\text{V}\$ and that \$V_o\$ is \$2\cdot i_1\$ or \$10\:\text{V}\$ less, so \$V_o=20\:\text{V}\$.

And, finally, you could have just assigned a new unknown current variable, through the dependent source, and developed two KCL equations using that unknown current, plus your constraint equation, and solved three equations in three unknowns to get the same results, as well.

Lots of ways of going. Just wanted to point this out to help stretch and exercise your thinking processes when looking at a problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I have solved it the same way.It took more time to think about it and then I solved it correctly.But why you are impressed ?

Comment: @HomerJay You are very persistent and you are obviously working hard. That's impressive to me. It's something I look up to and respect.

Comment: I try my best.But I have always questions.Thank you for your good words.